# Launch Google Place Picker Within Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

Is it possible to have Google's Place Picker display within a fragment on a page such that the place picker only takes up a small portion of the space rather than being full screen?

The place picker seems like the perfect tool that I need, however I would like to display some of my own text above the place picker along with a few buttons or the like below it. I tried putting it into a frameLayout that takes up just a small portion of space in my fragment however I believe this:

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
Intent intent = builder.build(getActivity());
startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Is probably what is causing it to go full screen. Is there a way I can start the place picker without having to launch an activity for it or at least be able to have it launch within a window rather than being full screen? I haven't seen any examples of this being done online.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think the reason being is that they want their solution to be compatible with all their users, so they used Activity so that everyone could use it.

In order for you to be able to integrate it inside your own view would have been something like a fragment, but that would bring down their compatibility.